# Google Charts format series type dynamically

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

How can I dynamically set google chart series type based on a array of objects?

Example:

Basic chart options

```
var options = {
    title: "Custom Chart",
    pointSize: 5,
    backgroundColor: { fill: 'white' },
    chartArea: { top: 40 },
    width: 600,
    height: 330,
};
```

My array that holds series type info is like this:

```
var sTypes = ["line", "bars", "line"];
```

The chart series type format is done like this:

```
series: {1: {type: "line"}}
```

How can I transform, dynamically, my array into something like that? ... then somehow append those extra options to the basic options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've found the answer:

```
var customSeries = {};
for (i = 0; i < sTypes.length; i++) {
    customSeries[i] = { type: sTypes[i] };
}
```

Then I can set:

```
var options = {..., series: customSeries };
```